# Amazon S3: Unable to decrypt symmetric key from object metadata : Illegal key size or default parameters

Tags: java, amazon-s3, encryption-symmetric

I am using AmazonS3EncryptionClient. I wrote a code to connect to S3 and download the data. The code works all fine from eclipse but when I create a jar out of it and try to run it, it gives the following error
`Unable to decrypt symmetric key from object metadata : Illegal key size or default parameters`

I am using symmetric encryption and the key is stored in a file. The file is being properly accessed from Eclipse as well as the jar.

What can be missing while running the code from the jar?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your private-key is some how invalid, most probably it is not in the JAR file or in classpath, can you make sure the code has access to the key

to check the file

```
jar tf <your jar> | grep <keyname>
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing the similar error when executing in eclipse itself. I have also made sure the key file is accessible to the program. do you have any idea?